# Как правильно запустить Discord-бота в потоке?

Tags: python, многопоточность, discord

Работаю с `PyQt5`. Нужно запустить Discord-бота вместе с остальным потоком.

```
def BOT_RUN():
    print("FUNC: BOT_RUN")
    bot.run(config.BOT_TOKEN)
```

```
class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        i = ''
        self.msleep(300)
        self.threadSignal.connect(BOT_RUN)
        self.threadSignal.connect(CHECK_CSVS)
        self.threadSignal.connect(SERVER_MONITORING)
        self.threadSignal.emit(i)
        self.threadSignal.disconnect(CHECK_CSVS)
```

`self.threadSignal.connect(BOT_RUN)` - срабатывает и запускает бота, но приложение закрывается. Будто, запустил бота и это ему хватает.

Для дебага написал в каждой функции `print("FUNC: функция")`, чтобы понять, запускаются ли остальные функции.
Получается что не запускается:

```
FUNC: BOT_RUN
PS C:\Users\...\Desktop\LOGGER>
```

Как продолжить дальнейшее действия кода после запуска бота?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как соединить два разных потока?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1293476/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ лежит в данной теме. Этот способ отлично работает в `WorkThread()`.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1294990/340378